# How to create array with single quotes in Bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, list, shell

I have this list/array:

```
declare -a LISTNODES=('servername node="{'region': 'primary', 'zone': 'east'}"' 'servername node="{'region': 'primary', 'zone': 'west'}"');
```

The problem is that when I print my list in a for loop I get the following:

```
servername
node="{region:
primary,
zone:
east}"
```

While the above needs to be together in the loop so I want to print

```
servername node="{'region': 'primary', 'zone': 'east'}"
servername node="{'region': 'primary', 'zone': 'west'}"
```

Comment: protect your inner `'` with backslashes

Comment: @Thomas: That doesn't work in Bash (nor any POSIX-compliant shell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems.

The main problem is in code you didn't post, but you've posted enough information to make it apparent that you're writing something like this:

```
for node in ${LISTNODES[@]}
```

or something like this:

```
for node in ${LISTNODES[*]}
```

instead of something like this:

```
for node in "${LISTNODES[@]}"
```

. So, you're triggering filename-expansion and word-splitting on the contents of `LISTNODES`.

The second problem is that you can't include single-quotes inside a single-quoted string; `'foo'bar'baz'` means `foobarbaz` (because it's `'foo'`, plus `bar`, plus `'baz'`) rather than `foo'bar'baz`. The easiest way to fix that is to use a double-quoted string for that part:

```
declare -a LISTNODES=(
  'servername node="{'"'"'region'"'"': '"'"'primary'"'"', '"'"'zone'"'"': '"'"'east'"'"'}"'
  'servername node="{'"'"'region'"'"': '"'"'primary'"'"', '"'"'zone'"'"': 'west'"'"'}"'
)
```

(so, basically just write `'"'"'` wherever you need `'` inside a single-quoted string).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$''` quotation notation to evalauate backslashes, and then just escape the single quotes inside the string. I personally think this is far simpler and easier to read than a mess of hundreds of single and double quotes.

```
declare -a LISTNODES=(
$'servername node="{\'region\': \'primary\', \'zone\': \'east\'}"'
$'servername node="{\'region\': \'primary\', \'zone\': \'west\'}"'
)
```

Also as noted in other answers you need to quote the variables

```
for value in "${LISTNODES[@]}"; do

echo "$value"

done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can drop the outermost quotes and directly escape the necessary spaces with a backslash, removing the nesting problem altogether.

```
declare -a LISTNODES=(
  servername\ node="{'region': 'primary', 'zone': 'east'}"
  servername\ node="{'region': 'primary', 'zone': 'west'}"
)
```

Then use a loop as suggested by ruakh:

```
for node in "$LISTNODES[@]"; do
    echo "$node"
```

Comment: But than I seem to lose my " .." after node=.. Isn't it?

Comment: @Anonymous yeah this will lose the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You should quote the variables properly,

```
$ for value in "${LISTNODES[@]}"; 
> do 
>      echo "$value"; 
> done
servername node="{region: primary, zone: east}"
node="{region: primary, zone: west}"
```

**Note** : Here `"${LISTNODES[@]}"` is important so that each of the element in array is taken up properly with the spaces in them till the delimiter `,`

If not, bash will take both space and comma as separators and iterate though each of them